# How do I allow Java client TLS10 connections?

Tags: java, eclipse, mssql-jdbc

While attempting to do a hello world MSSQL JDBC connection in Eclipse with Java 16, I'm getting this error:

`"...server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]..."`

Upon searching, it appears my Java client is not allowing this TLS version while trying to connect to my deprecated MSSQL instance. How do I enable it?

Here's how I added the MSSQL JDBC driver:

- Download jar driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
- Add jar to build path, under Class path, jar for java version (version listed above)

Comment: Wow, TLS 1.1 was introduced 16.5 years ago. Uh, you're kinda lacking when it comes to upgrades, but kudo's for keeping that server running for that long :P

Comment: True, but it's the only mssql I have a license for & it's only a sandbox. No point fixing a "security issue" that's not even open to the public. Besides, just wanted to spend time developing java, not down a mssql rabbit hole as we all know this turns into! Thx for feedback

Answer (score 4):

**TLS 1.0 and 1.1** are disabled by default in latest Java versions (OpenJDK 11.0.11 onwards). Because these versions of TLS have weakened over time and lack support for stronger, more modern algorithms.

**Solution:**

Patch your MSSQL server and enable TLS1.2 on your MSSQL Server as per the Microsoft KB article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe

**Alternate Solutions**: (Prone to security risks)

1. Enabling them by doing modification in existing java.security file of installed JDK as mentioned in Kevin's answer.
2. Or by overriding java.security for your specific application as given below.(**preferred**)

- Create a file named enableLegacyTLS.security.
- In that file, add an entry for jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms with the same contents as the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms property in the java.security file.

> ```
> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
>  DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL,...
> ```

- Remove **TLSv1, TLSv1.1,** from the list on the enableLegacyTLS.security.
- Start your application with -Djava.security.properties=path/to/enableLegacyTLS.security

Note: In last point, When you use a double equals sign (==), you tell the JVM to ignore the default java.security file and load only this file. But if a single equals sign (=) is used, it loads both your copy and superimposes it over the default java.security file

Comment: You can even hand the modified value to your JVM on startup, using `-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=<list of modified algorithms>`.

Answer (score 3):

Solution (though be aware of security risks):

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\conf\security\java.security
- Or C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\java.security
- Remove "TLSv1, TLSv1.1, " from this line:

`jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \`

`DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL`