# How do I force a Java (17) exported application to use TLS 1.2, not TLS 1.0?

Tags: java, tls1.2

I have a Java (17) application that works inside [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), but it does not work when exported into a JAR file.  The exported JAR file tries to connect to the SQL server using [TLS 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0) (`TLS10`).  Is there a way to force the exported file to use TLS 1.2? The exported JAR file has *mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar* as does Eclipse. JRE System Library - JavaSE-1.8

I have tried multiple connection strings, and the current one is:
"jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME\sqlexpress;user=USERID;password=PASSWORD";

The error we get is:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:00444b11-89ec-4bba-81d5-4d268e4afd68

Comment: What is the driver version?  What is the exact error message?  What is the connection string (with credentials/server name redacted)?

Comment: Like Andrew said: we need to confirm your "assumptions".  Please [Edit] your post and tell us 1) the exact error message being returned from MSSQL (copy/paste the text), 2) Your Java SQL driver (exactly name and version) 3) Your MSSQL version.  I suspect that Java might not be the problem at all, and maybe your JDBC driver is *ALREADY* using TLS 1.2++

Comment: BTW: Makato is 100% correct - you really need to upgrade your MSSQL infrastructure.  But this link might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623611/how-do-i-allow-java-client-tls10-connections

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

[As of Java 16, TLS versions lower than 1.1 are disabled.](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8202343)

The preferred option would be to update the server to a newer TLS technology.  <s>This might work in Java 11 as well but there is no guarantee that it will continue to work with new updates.</s>  There are notes that suggest that [this was backported to LTS versions as well](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8258597), so there's no good guarantee that TLS v1.1 or below will function.

Comment: Exported application works if we update java security file to allow the use of TLS10